# D3 / Javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am having trouble understanding how to manipulate my data in javascript.  Basically I am working on some D3 visualizations, where I need to manipulate my data in certain ways for it to work in the visual.  Here I am trying to add some new data, based on existing data, in my Array of objects.

Basically I am trying to understand how to "add" new data / properties for each of my objects in the array.

Here is what the array looks like: 
[image: Titanic Array of Objects]

Here is what I am trying to do to return a new array of augmented objects (with 4 new keys):

```
      function getTileData(rawdata) {
        return data.map(function(d,i) {
          // positioning for square visual
          // stored here to make it easier
          // to keep track of.
          d.col = i % numPerRow;
          d.x = d.col * (squareSize + squarePad);
          d.row = Math.floor(i / numPerRow);
          d.y = d.row * (squareSize + squarePad);
          return d;
        });
      };
```

Any thoughts?  Basically I was curious about: 
1. Am I on the right track with the map method above?
2. Is there a better way to add this new information? I am quite green with data in javascript.

Comment: you want to add *columns* on *top* of the table?

Comment: Drew - sorry.  I wrote that in a rush and it was poor.  I made some edits, which I hope makes my trouble more clear.

Answer (score 0):

So after some real investigation I figured out that I needed to be reforming my code in the following fashion:

```
      function parseTileData(rawdata) {
        var new_data2 = rawdata.map(function(d,i) { 
            d.col = i % numPerRow;
            d.x = d.col * (squareSize + squarePad);
            d.row = Math.floor(i / numPerRow);
            d.y = d.row * (squareSize + squarePad);
            return d;
        });

        return new_data2;
      };
```

Here I have a new array created from the mapped array with the correct syntax to create the new columns THEN return the item as its iterating through.

Answer (score 0):

1. You want to manipulate `rawdata` so you should `return rawdata.map...`.
2. Where have you declared `numPerRow`?
3. This will create a whole new object with these properties added and you'll now have 2 objects of such large size. If you no longer need the rawdata, I think you'll be better off using an IIFE to fetch the `rawdata` and store it in an outer scope variable so that you only have the new data saving you the memory and increasing the performance with larger datasets. Here is an example:

   ```
   (function(){
       //Fetch the rawdata here using an AJAX request
       $.ajax({
           ...
           success: assignData
       })
   })();
   //As soon as the above ends, rawData goes out of scope, leaving you with only the new data. 
   //I may be wrong in assuming that you'll need rawdata only once.

   var newData = [], numPerRow = //your nums per row;
   function assignData(data){
       data.map(function(d,i){
           d.col = i % numPerRow;
           d.x = d.col * (squareSize + squarePad);
           d.row = Math.floor(i / numPerRow);
           d.y = d.row * (squareSize + squarePad);
           newData.push(d);
       });
   }
   ```